# Sending an array from a form

Tags: python, django

use the [] symbol in the name of the form field you are submitting like:

`input type=checkbox name=whatever[] value=1`

`input type=checkbox name=whatever[] value=2`

`input type=checkbox name=whatever[] value=3`

`input type=checkbox name=whatever[] value=4`

In PHP
when you post, this will come in as

```
$whatever = array("1", "2", "3", "4");
```

and you can access them like:

```
$whatever[0]
```

which will yield you "1"

But I have python and django template.

`z=[]`

`z = request.POST['whatever[]']

 s = ','.join(str(n) for n in z)`

I want to recive this
`s =1,2,3,4` 
but instead of this I habe only the last digit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed the [] symbol in the name. And after z = request.POST.getlist('whatever')

But this is not the way. Read [django forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)